# How do I get the code after the for-loop to not run until the for-loop has completed its interations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I stop the alert function from running until after the for loop has completed all its interations?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $('#ponyDiv').animate({left: '200px'}, 2000); 
    }
    alert("here");
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling animate() in a loop?

Comment: This is a simpler example of much more complicated code I'm working with. If I can solve this problem, my code will work. Lets change it to $('#pony' + i).animate({left: '200px'}, 2000);

Comment: I could maybe see a use for this if you were using relative measurements (+200px), but not a hard coded measurement. Insight on what you are trying to do exactly would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: when calling animate() in a loop, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var completed = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $('#ponyDiv'+i).animate({
            left: '200px'
        }, 200, function () {
            if (completed++ == 7) alert("here");
        });
    }
});
```

---

Use [JQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) 'complete' callback which will be called right after your animation has completed:

```
  $('#ponyDiv').animate({left: '200px'}, 2000, function() {
    alert('here');
  });
```

Comment: Yes, beside this answer I've commented on PO's question to get to know why he's calling animate() in a loop.

Comment: I assume, though possibly incorrectly, that it is meant to be something more like `$('#ponyDiv' + i)...`

Comment: Yes it is. $('#pony' + i).animate({left: '200px'}, 2000);

Comment: `$("#ponyDiv"+[1,2,3,4].join(",#ponyDiv")).animate(..., function(){...})` or for any div with an id that starts with `ponyDiv` `$("[id^=ponyDiv]").animate(..., function(){...})`

Answer (score 1):

This will alert when the loop is completed (not when the final animation is completed).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $('#ponyDiv' + i).animate({left: '200px'}, 2000);
        if(i === 8){
            alert("here");
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use deferred:

```
$.when($('[id^=pony]').animate({left:'200px'},2000))
    .then(function() { alert('done'); });
```

it's better of course to use a class than attribute starts with on id, but you get the gist of it.